# grep unique occurrences

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I have a log file (`file.log`) with multiple occurrences of ids i.e. `82244956` in a file. 
`file.log` has been created using the command :

```
gzip -cd /opt/log.gz | grep "JBOSS1-1" >> ~/file.log
```

Example :

```
2012-04-10 09:01:18,196 LOG  (7ysdhsdjfhsdhjkwe:IN) JBOSS1-1 (RP-yedgdh5567) [PayPalWeb] Fetch data with id: 82244956  
2012-04-10 09:02:18,196 LOG  (24343sdjjkidgyuwe:IN) JBOSS1-1 (RP-yedgdh5567) [PayPalWeb] Fetch data with id: 82244956  
2012-04-10 09:03:18,196 LOG  (6744443jfhsdgyuwe:IN) JBOSS1-1 (RP-yedgdh5567) [PayPalWeb] Fetch data with id: 82244957  
2012-04-10 09:04:18,196 LOG  (7ysdhsd5677dgyuwe:IN) JBOSS1-1 (RP-yedgdh5567) [PayPalWeb] Fetch data with id: 82244957
```

Likewise we have 10000 rows with different ids (but each id repeating 2-3 times. Example top and bottom 2 rows in this example are repeating with id 82244956 and 82244957 respectively). We need result set based on UNIQUE ids (any row from the matched ids)i.e.:

```
2012-04-10 09:01:18,196 LOG  (7ysdhsdjfhsdhjkwe:IN) JBOSS1-1 (RP-yedgdh5567) [PayPalWeb] Fetch data with id: 82244956  
2012-04-10 09:03:18,196 LOG  (6744443jfhsdgyuwe:IN) JBOSS1-1 (RP-yedgdh5567) [PayPalWeb] Fetch data with id: 82244957
```

I tried to awk program on Linux but not a successful one :

```
awk ' { arr[$1]=$0 } END { for ( key in arr ) { print arr[key] } } ' file.log >> final-report.log
```

Or a better way would be to create `file.log` with distinct ids Only.

Please advise how can I modify it?

Comment: Does the sort order matter? If not, you can pipe your file through `sort` and then again through `uniq` to give you the unique lines. You'd need to pass some parameters to specify by which field you want them sorted etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$1` is the first field, the date.  The `id` is the last field, `$NF` in `awk` parlance.  So:

```
awk '{arr[$NF] = $0} END { for (key in arr) { print arr[key] } }' file.log >> final-report.log
```

This keeps the last record with the given key.  To keep the first record, you'd have to do a conditional assignment in the main processing part of the script.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '!_[$NF]++' file.log >> final-report.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the result by running the following script. To keep the first record, you should do a conditional judgment in the main processing part of the script.

```
awk -F"\t" '{delete arr;split($0,arr,"id:"); id_num=arr[2];
             if(!(id_num in dic)){line[id_num]=$0;dic[id_num];}}
            END{for(i in line)print line[i] }' file.log  > result.log
```